# Azure AMS node js app failing to make a TLS 1.2 connection

Tags: node.js, azure, ssl, request, tls1.2

I have a node js app running as mobile service on Azure AMS. I have been  using request library to do the HTTPS get/post api calls to an external server. Everything use to work fine till a few days ago when the external entity decided to discontinue supporting TLS 1.0 and below.

I was wondering if someone knows of any known issues of Azure AMS blocking/failing TLS 1.1/1.2 communications with external hosts? That host uses a valid SSL certificate being issued by DigiCert.

Inside my code, I have already tried few things to explicitly tell nodejs to use TLS 1.1 / 1.2 but that didn't work.

```
var httpRequest = require("request"),
https = require('https');

https.globalAgent.options.secureProtocol = 'TLSv1_2_method'; // Instructing to use TLS 1.2
....


httpRequest.post('https://external-api-url.com', {
    'json': true,
    'body': params,
    'timeout': 20000,
    'jar': false,
    'headers': {
        "Arr-Disable-Session-Affinity": true
    }

}, function(err, response, body) {
    // Code to handle response.
});
```

Besides globalAgent, I also tried setting secureProtocol from agentOptions as well as directly from within the options object. None of the approaches worked.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank-you.

Comment: I have never used TLS 1.2 on Node but on ASP.NET WebAPI recently. What I know this, if you want to use TLS 1.2 you need 1) Win 08R2 or later. 2) Update register keys `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols`, add `TLS 1.1\Client` `TLS 1.1\Server` `TLS 1.2\Client` `TLS 1.2\Server` with keys `Enabled = 0x01` and `DisabledByDefault = 0x00`. Maybe you can have a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is cause of the version of NodeJS on Azure Mobile Service.

The version of NodeJS on Azure Mobile Service is v0.8.28. You can see it at the section "AppSettings" of the Azure Kudu Env page https://<your_ams_name>.scm.azure-mobile.net/Env , as the picture below.

[image]

However, NodeJS add TLS 1.1/1.2 to secureProtocol list since the version 0.11.6, as the picture below.

[image]

So when the external entity decided to discontinue supporting TLS 1.0, your nodejs app didn't work.

But you can follow the NodeJS examples with Https APIs support TLS or Request Module with API support TLS/SSL Protocol to set options.key & options.cert to do it.
Please refer to https://nodejs.org/docs/v0.8.28/api/https.html#https_https_request_options_callback and https://github.com/request/request#tlsssl-protocol.

Example:

```
var fs = require('fs')
    , path = require('path')
    , certFile = path.resolve(__dirname, 'ssl/client.crt')
    , keyFile = path.resolve(__dirname, 'ssl/client.key')
    , request = require('request');

https.globalAgent.options.cert = certFile;
https.globalAgent.options.key = keyFil;
```

Best Regards.

Comment: You might be right. Though my package.json sets node version to 0.12.0. Doesn't that have any effect? Anyways, I'll get back to you after confirming. Thanks!

Comment: Peter Pan - You were absolutely right about the version. It's 0.8.28 though I am still stumped that it did not pick the version instruction from package.json file (set to 0.12.0). Any idea why? 

I'll try the globalAgent cert and key approach but was wondering if nodejs version can some how be updated? I am on a free tier so not sure if Azure will update the runtime for me.
 
Your comment can be accepted as the answer.

Comment: @imkhoja The TLS secureProtocol support is integrated into NodeJS so that it not works through set the higher version in package.json. The runtime update of NodeJS or other languages follow the Azure update, not specially update for anyone. If you need to use the sepcial version Node, I suggest to use Azure VM and install it by yourself. Thanks for your marked answer.